# $(-1,0,1)$-square matrix has different line sums?

Tags: matrices, number-theory, block-matrices, random-matrices

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with coefficients from the set $\{-1,0,1\}$. Let $r_i$ and $c_i$ denote the sum of the elements of the $i$-th row and column of $A$ respectively. For which $n$ is it possible that the numbers $r_1,...,r_n,c_1,...,c_n$ be different pairwise?

If $n$ is even, I am able to construct such a matrix, which I call $A_n$.
$$
A_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
A_4=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\-1&1&1&1\\-1&-1&0&1\\-1&-1&-1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
A_{n+2}=\begin{pmatrix}1& \begin{matrix}1&\cdots&1\end{matrix} &1\\ \begin{matrix}-1\\\vdots\\-1\end{matrix} &A_n&\begin{matrix}1\\\vdots\\1\end{matrix}\\-1&\begin{matrix}-1&\cdots&-1\end{matrix}&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Not hard to check that these matrices have all different line (row or column) sums.

However, if $n$ is odd, it seems impossible to construct such a matrix. I'd like to prove that if $n$ is odd, any $n\times n$ matrix with coefficients from the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ has two lines with the same sum of elements. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Pigeonhole principle ?

Comment: It looks like you've been able to construct these matrices for even n inductively by using a previously constructed matrix. However, clearly there's no $A_1$ which satisfies the property you want. Maybe if you could prove that if $A_{2n+1}$ satisfies the property, then the $2n-1 \times 2n-1$ matrix at the centre also must satisfy it. If this were true then it would be easy to prove inductively that no such matrices exist for odd numbers. Not sure if this will work though; problem looks very rough.

Comment: @OgglieOstrich of course, backwards induction. But I can't find a way to derive a $A_{2k-1}$ from $A_{2k+1}$.

Comment: You wouldn't have to derive an explicit expression, just prove that if $A_{2k+1}$ satisfies your property, then so does the matrix in the centre of it. Or you could try to prove the contrapositive. I've attempted to problem a little and got nothing though so maybe this isn't the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a belated answer, but here's a proof in French:
https://oeis.org/A049475/a049475.pdf#page=4

Luca shows that such matrices exist when $n$ is even. We show that such matrices exist only when $n$ is even by showing that number of rows with strictly positive sums must be exactly $\frac{n}{2}$ or number of rows with strictly negative sums must be exactly $\frac{n}{2}$ (so for odd $n$, $\frac{n}{2}$ is not an integer).

Note that there are possibly $2n+1$ different sums in total (from $-n$ to $n$), while we have $n$ rows and $n$ columns, so we require $2n$ different sums. There is exactly one sum is missing. Assume the missing sum is $X$. WLOG assume $X\le 0$ because otherwise we can negate all elements in the matrix. So we have $-n\le X\le 0$.
In this way, we can see that we have exactly $N$ rows or columns with strictly positive sums, and also exactly $N$ rows or columns with non-positive sums.

By rearranging rows and columns, we can let first several rows have all strictly positive sums, following by rows with non-positive sums. Assume we have $r$ rows with positive sums, $s$ rows with non-positive sums. Similarly, let first several columns have all strictly positive sums (assume we have $p$ columns), followed by $q$ columns with non-positive sums. Let $x$ be the sum of $pr$ elements on the top left corner (i.e. intersection of rows with strictly positive sum and columns with strictly negative sum, same follows). Let $u$ be the sum of $qr$ elements on top right corner; let $v$ be the sum of $ps$ elements on bottom left corner; let $y$ be the sum of $qs$ elements on bottom right corner.

[image]

Let $A$ be the row and column sums of all strictly positive rows and columns (so it's a sum of $p + r$ rows and columns). We have $A = 2x + u + v$. Also since all strictly positive sums appear exactly once, we have $A = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Similarly, let $B$ the row and column sums of all non-positive rows and columns. We have $B = 2y + u + v = -\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - X$. So $A - B = 2(x-y) = n(n+1) + X$.

From definition, we have $p+q = n$ (because matrix has exactly $n$ rows) and $p+r = n$ (because all strictly positive row or column sums appear exactly once), and similarly $r+s = q + r = n$. So $p=s$ and $q=r$. Note that all elements are -1, 0, 1, so we have $|x|\le pr = pq$ and $|y|\le qs = pq$. So $2(x-y)\le 4pq$.

Since $n(n+1)+X = 2(x-y)$, we have $n(n+1)+X\le 4pq$. Also $n = p+q$, we have
$$n+X\le 4pq-N^2=4pq-(p+q)^2=-(p-q)^2\le 0$$. Note that $-n\le X\le 0$ because it's a non-positive missing sum, we have $n+X\ge 0$. Therefore we know $X = -n$ (i.e. the missing sum must be $-n$) and $p=q$ (i.e. umber of rows with strictly positive sums must be exactly $\frac{n}{2}$).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).